# Hot reload in docker based Vue project

Tags: docker, vue.js, websocket, vuejs3, webpack-dev-server

Hi I have a problem with my project in vue.

I have frontend backend and Db for backend in docker.

This is the vue.config.js configuration:

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  configureWebpack: {
    entry: "./src/main.js",
    devServer: {
      hot: true,
    },
    watch: true,
    watchOptions: {
        ignored: /node_modules/,
        poll: 500,
    },
},
  transpileDependencies: true
})
```

container during creation installs npm and packages given in package.json by itself:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@morioh/v-smooth-scrollbar": "^1.0.3",
    "@vuepic/vue-datepicker": "^4.2.0",
    "@vueuse/core": "^9.13.0",
    "ajax": "^0.0.4",
    "axios": "^1.3.3",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "mitt": "^3.0.0",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.2",
    "smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.4.4",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-axios": "^3.5.2",
    "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
    "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet": "^0.8.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.3",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "@vue/typescript/recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 2020
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

I'm posting everything so there's no confusion :)

Until yesterday everything worked fine for me but today after restarting the container the hot reload option of the page stopped working.

when the container starts I get this output:

```
frontend    |   App running at:
frontend    |   - Local:   http://localhost:8080/
frontend    |   - Network: http://172.26.0.4:8080/
frontend    |
No issues found.
```

when I fire up the page in the browser using http://localhost:8080 the page loads but the live reloading option when I save from changes has stopped working.

In the console I can see that the browser tries to download the update but gets no response

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://172.26.0.4:8080/ws' failed: 
WebSocketClient @ WebSocketClient.js?5586:16
initSocket @ socket.js?d6e0:24
eval @ socket.js?d6e0:48
```

I tried putting up containers from scratch.

I took older versions of kyod but after compose up still this option does not work

When I refresh the page manually the content changes correctly.

Do you have any idea what the fault could be

In addition, on other computers it works correctly.

They compiled the whole project later than I did, so if it depended on some node-modules it wouldn't work either.
Anyway, I've been trying to create containers from scratch myself for 2 days now so no node_ modules are obsolete.
The problem is not in the config because a day ago it was working.
Or is there something on my comp that may be blocking traffic to ws://172.26.0.4:8080/ws

Additionally, it looks identical on other browsers.

I am currently putting up a vm to check it still like this but would love to hear advice on what else I can check.

Thanks for your interactions in advance and counting on you!

Answer (score 0):

Aditional info:

This is my container inspect:

```
[
{
    "Id": "625967de365da0d8b22436d525c8b355a6388b171cbb6065a58b8dce5cf6308e",
    "Created": "2023-04-09T13:30:45.128344216Z",
    "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
    "Args": [
        "npm",
        "run",
        "serve"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 6155,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2023-04-09T13:30:55.597778809Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:17aa7ddc26c8faa172749252f89ac6e67e53cf104c9aade0ce8f866fd378405e",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/625967de365da0d8b22436d525c8b355a6388b171cbb6065a58b8dce5cf6308e/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/625967de365da0d8b22436d525c8b355a6388b171cbb6065a58b8dce5cf6308e/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/625967de365da0d8b22436d525c8b355a6388b171cbb6065a58b8dce5cf6308e/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/625967de365da0d8b22436d525c8b355a6388b171cbb6065a58b8dce5cf6308e/625967de365da0d8b22436d525c8b355a6388b171cbb6065a58b8dce5cf6308e-json.log",
    "Name": "/frontend",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "overlay2",
    "Platform": "linux",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "C:\\Users\\kubak\\Documents\\GitHub\\yourcar24\\frontend:/app:rw"
        ],
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "yourcar24_default",
        "PortBindings": {
            "8080/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ]
        },
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": false,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "CgroupnsMode": "private",
        "Dns": null,
        "DnsOptions": null,
        "DnsSearch": null,
        "ExtraHosts": [],
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "private",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "Runtime": "runc",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": null,
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DeviceRequests": null,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "OomKillDisable": null,
        "PidsLimit": null,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Target": "/app/node_modules",
                "VolumeOptions": {}
            }
        ],
        "MaskedPaths": [
            "/proc/asound",
            "/proc/acpi",
            "/proc/kcore",
            "/proc/keys",
            "/proc/latency_stats",
            "/proc/timer_list",
            "/proc/timer_stats",
            "/proc/sched_debug",
            "/proc/scsi",
            "/sys/firmware"
        ],
        "ReadonlyPaths": [
            "/proc/bus",
            "/proc/fs",
            "/proc/irq",
            "/proc/sys",
            "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
        ]
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6673870013c91f39037354420092aa515c9d5cef85f23ebd82550deddafb89fe-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cd5p9dvr5c7dbcha8dtxbme1m/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/to42q27jjhra2yqc7ir9wj5j2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/xh0ysmffu4p9v8ftknpf33je9/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/is9l099vfhqmvx05r231znk1n/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5b1b4bc3f17d76f08c342ddc86f8130386ce811b6458c825f17aafb543ca181a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/88184b84b65868f1d4734f58ce65ba5d95e275eec17bc5c5c83e4158e54ff75d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0f12aa8e3716d8c56fdb0d7fbaab97ccf1bf9a3c1220d54858c3b1ab06be71df/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6ae91c5d23a1ef5d5e3c6eaa95ccbaa2be5e1b1c7373aa0cebc6fe8598c6c8ef/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6673870013c91f39037354420092aa515c9d5cef85f23ebd82550deddafb89fe/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6673870013c91f39037354420092aa515c9d5cef85f23ebd82550deddafb89fe/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6673870013c91f39037354420092aa515c9d5cef85f23ebd82550deddafb89fe/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "C:\\Users\\kubak\\Documents\\GitHub\\yourcar24\\frontend",
            "Destination": "/app",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        },
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "e88cbe5ad0d3e021e966733cf8282771e90fc46bde83ea8fce699526e1b2f960",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/e88cbe5ad0d3e021e966733cf8282771e90fc46bde83ea8fce699526e1b2f960/_data",
            "Destination": "/app/node_modules",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "z",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
    ],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "625967de365d",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": true,
        "AttachStderr": true,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "8080/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true",
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "NODE_VERSION=19.8.1",
            "YARN_VERSION=1.22.19"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "npm",
            "run",
            "serve"
        ],
        "Image": "yourcar24-frontend",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "/app",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "docker-entrypoint.sh"
        ],
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "758ad9f8455cf7bcbb71af70db99dffaff094db18fc300027e84c7c7732f0322",
            "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
            "com.docker.compose.depends_on": "backend:service_started:false",
            "com.docker.compose.image": "sha256:17aa7ddc26c8faa172749252f89ac6e67e53cf104c9aade0ce8f866fd378405e",
            "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "yourcar24",
            "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "C:\\Users\\kubak\\Documents\\GitHub\\yourcar24\\docker-compose.yaml",
            "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "C:\\Users\\kubak\\Documents\\GitHub\\yourcar24",
            "com.docker.compose.replace": "6ce5b392b35312a4cf6c570489499d92ce1caac3d7277c180fea31f50be29e62",
            "com.docker.compose.service": "frontend",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.17.2"
        }
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "e05a105a74ff2f8d8447668bb81fd3fef49328bc033760b0bad3089acc578519",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "8080/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/e05a105a74ff",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "",
        "Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "",
        "IPPrefixLen": 0,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "",
        "Networks": {
            "yourcar24_default": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "frontend",
                    "frontend",
                    "625967de365d"
                ],
                "NetworkID": "3e68f8d62150de8f8ca5a3f89602cf9b58d7f98a68169e9b5ab8fe3bbbd4a30e",
                "EndpointID": "9da94224f0fcf2d50edb5998b8824b71c72c52459f081c8801361458b6d3c2b1",
                "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.19.0.4",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:04",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

]